# sklearn CountVectorizer

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I am having doubts using vocabulary_.get , the code is as follows. 
As seen below I have used CountVectorizer in one of the machine learning exercises, to get the count of occurrences of a particular word.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
s1 = 'KJ YOU WILL BE FINE'
s2 = 'ABHI IS MY BESTIE'
s3 = 'sam is my bestie'
frnd_list = [s1,s2,s3]
bag_of_words = vectorizer.fit(frnd_list)
bag_of_words = vectorizer.transform(frnd_list)
print(bag_of_words)
# To get the feature word number from word 
#for eg:
print(vectorizer.vocabulary_.get('bestie'))
print(vectorizer.vocabulary_.get('BESTIE'))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Bag_of_words is :
(0, 1)  1
(0, 3)  1
(0, 5)  1
(0, 8)  1
(0, 9)  1
(1, 0)  1
(1, 2)  1
(1, 4)  1
(1, 6)  1
(2, 2)  1
(2, 4)  1
(2, 6)  1
(2, 7)  1

'bestie' has  feature number:
 2
'BESTIE' has feature number:
 None
```

Hence my doubt is that why 'bistie' shows correct feature number i.e 2 and 'BESTIE' shows None . Doesn't vocabulary_.get work well with capital vectors?

Answer (score 2):

`CountVectorizer` takes a parameter `lowercase` that defaults to `True`, as stated in the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn-feature-extraction-text-countvectorizer):

> ```
> lowercase : boolean, True by default
>     Convert all characters to lowercase before tokenizing.
> ```

change that to `False` if you want to treat lowercase and uppercase differently.

Answer (score 0):

countvectorizer takes a parameter "lowercase" and by default its value is true

If we want to differentiate both upper and lower case letters then set lowercase=False

[image]

for more information click here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html